# Automatically insert column footnotes after each column (multicol+parnotes)?

Tags: footnotes, multicol, columns, parnotes

I can *simulate* a column footnotes in multicol environment using parnotes like this. (It is needed because multicol does not support this.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=6mm]{geometry} % using 4 columns, landscape
\usepackage{multicol} % multi column layout
\usepackage{parnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand\parnotefmt[1]{%
  \footnoterule\footnotesize
  #1
}
\renewcommand\parnoteintercmd{\newline\noindent}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{4} % 4 columns
\let\footnote\parnote
\lipsum[1-4]
Text comes here.\footnote{footnote text here} text continues
%%%% THIS LINE needs to be put in every column end, but how to determine it? %%%%
\hfill\vfill\parnotes\columnbreak and it continues here...
%%%% END THIS  %%%%
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

This works OK. The problem is that I have to manually adjust the footnotes every time I change something. i.e. I have to determine manually when a column ends and insert it there. Can this be automated? The best would be if I could somehow hook up `\vfill\parnotes` at a column break?

Comment: I am going to use the package `flowfram` instead. It can handle column footnotes quite nicely.